# How can I use an element id on multiple places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little problem that has been hard to solve, harder than I believed. I assume there will be a simple answer to this one.

So, I have made a timer using javascript, the timer works fine and that's not a problem. However, I am using this to define the timer:

```
document.getElementById("timerz").innerHTML = 0;
```

And then using this to display the timer

```
<span id=timerz></span>
```

I know that I can't use an element with the same ID on multiple places. However, I've tried this:

```
document.getElementsByClass("timerz").innerHTML = 0;
```

And then

```
<span class=timerz></span>
```

And it is still not working, how can I solve this? It's very strange.

Comment: Should be `document.getElementsByClassName` with an `s`. It will return you an array.

Comment: Oh, give me a second.

Comment: Put quotes around the attributes in your html:  `class="..."` and `id="..."`.

Comment: Still not working..

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('timerz')` ;)

Comment: That won't have an effect, but I just tried for sure. And it didn't work either

Comment: Don't forget it gives you an array, not an element, so you'll have to access its elements like `document.getElementsByClassName( ... )[0] ` or so.

Comment: This is simple js code and if its not working this only means that you have made a mistake somewhere else in your code

Comment: @zenoo it's a `NodeCollection`, which is array-like, but it's not an actual `Array`.

Comment: Pick your answer, dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here you need to understand how javascript works.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("timerz")
```

This will return an array of spans as we have used a same class for each span.
Now we need to iterate each element and than put html inside it.

**I recommed you to go through any javascript tutorial**

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("timerz")
for(span of spans){
 span.innerHTML = "0"
}
```

```html
<span class="timerz"> </span>
<span class="timerz"> </span>
<span class="timerz"> </span>
<span class="timerz"> </span>
```

Comment: Is `for...of` on `NodeCollection` widely supported as of now?

Comment: Old systems having internet explorer is not having compatibility as per mdn web docs else it is widely supported .

Answer (score 0):

use getElementsByClass with s

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("timerz")[0].innerHTML = 0;
```

or

```
var timerz = document.getElementsByClassName("timerz");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < timerz.length; i++) {
    timerz[i].innerHTML = 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Already tried

Comment: this is simply wrong - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: you can use  `var timerz = document.getElementsByClassName("timerz");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < timerz.length; i++) {
    timerz[i].innerHTML = 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you iterate over a NodeCollection (which returns whenever you use any query method that potentially can return more than one element like `document.querySelectorAll`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, `document.getElementsByTagName`):

```js
var timerz = document.getElementsByClassName("timerz");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(timerz, function(timer, index) {
    timer.textContent = `This is the timer with the index ${index}.`
})
```

```html
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
```

You have to use `Array.prototype.forEach.call` here because the data type returned by `document.getElementsByClassName`, despite being very **similar** to an `Array`, is not an *actual* Array. In some browsers `NodeCollection` may not have a method `forEach()`.

Another option is to create an actual Array from the NodeCollection:

```js
var timerz = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("timerz"));

timerz.forEach(function(timer, index) {
    timer.textContent = `This is the timer with the index ${index}.`
})
```

```html
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
<div class="timerz"></div>
```